# Go back button submits the form

Tags: symfony, symfony5

I'm currently having issues with my user's update form in Symfony.
It's all working good but when it comes to the button part there is a problem.

In my twig template I got this :

```
<div>
     <button onClick="window.history.back();">Go back</button>
     <button type="submit">Update</button>
</div>
```

When I click on the `Update` button it works and my user is updated but when I click it works too when I click on the `Go back` button, I'm redirected to the previous page but it sumbits the form.
I don't want the `Go back` button to sumbit the form, how can I do that ?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT :
There is my controller function for the update page

```
/**
* @Route("/admin/users/{id}/update", name="usersUpdate", methods={"GET","POST"})
* @IsGranted("ROLE_ADMIN")
*/
public function usersUpdate(User $user, Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationFormType::class, $user);
    $form->remove('plainPassword');
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();

        $this->container->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('validUpdate', 'L\'utilisateur a été mis a jour.');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('users');
    }

    return $this->render('admin/users/update.html.twig', [
        'registrationForm' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

Comment: You need to share more details - is that a GET or POST form?

Comment: This is a Symfony form built with the FormBuilderInterface of Symfony

Comment: I believe the default type of a button is submit. you should explicitly state `type="button"` for the back button. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button for details.

Comment: You need to specify `<button onClick="window.history.back();">Go back</button>` as `<button onClick="window.history.back();" type="button">Go back</button>`. Otherwise it defaults to `submit` when the button is placed inside `<form/>`. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jakumi and Yoshi figured it out !

It was due to the type of the button.
Adding `type="button"` to the `Go back` button was the solution.

---

Their answers :

> I believe the default type of a button is submit. you should explicitly state type="button" for the back button. see [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) for details. - [Jakumi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4275413/jakumi)

and

> You need to specify `<button onClick="window.history.back();">Go back</button>` as `<button onClick="window.history.back();" type="button">Go back</button>`. Otherwise it defaults to `sumbit` when the button is placed inside `<form/>`. Ref: [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) - [Yoshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/697154/yoshi)